# Ruby: n `[]=': string not matched (IndexError)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to loop through a file line by line, replacing substrings. I have a working script - but if someone could help me understand why *this* (my original) script doesn't work, I'd appreciate it

```
File.open('input3400.txt', 'rb') do |f|
  f.each_line do |i|
    File.write('input3400.txt', i["<aspect name="] = "hi")
  end
end
```

Basically, I want to search this file for all instances of `<aspect name=` and replace them with `hi`. I'm getting this output when I run:

> `[]=': string not matched (IndexError)
>
> `block (2 levels) in {top (required)}'
>
> `each_line'
>
> `block in {top (required)}'

Comment: So, is it a working script or not working script?

Comment: It's a not working script - I was given an alternate answer, but I really want to know why this (my original script) doesn't work; I'm pretty new to Ruby, so just trying to learn :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the error you have:

`i["<aspect name="] = "hi"`

this tries to substitute `"<aspect name="` with `"hi"` *but* raises a error when `"<aspect name="` is not a substring of desired string.

Then, you have to have a closer look to this line: 

`File.write('input3400.txt', i["<aspect name="] = "hi")`

why the assignment is passed as a second argument? The return value of an assignment on Ruby is its right-side, that's right, but why use assignment at all here then?

And, finally, `File.write('input3400.txt', i["<aspect name="] = "hi")` - it doesn't know anything about your current_line (`i`). Where do you want to `File.write` it?

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because `i["<aspect name="] = "hi"` will raise an `IndexError` exception if one of the line doesn't match the `<aspect name=` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors, first error is that the variable *i* is an String, where the method *[]* is trying to access the index `<aspect name=` which doesn't exist, and second error is that you cannot update a file that you opened for reading, you have to put the data in a temporal place and then overwrite the original file.

Try with this code:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'tempfile'

t_file = Tempfile.new('input3400_temp.txt')
File.open("input3400.txt", 'r') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    t_file.puts(line.gsub('<aspect name=', 'hi'))
  end
end
t_file.close
FileUtils.mv(t_file.path, "input3400.txt")
```

Comment: > first error is that the variable i is an String, where the method [] is trying to access the index <aspect name=
Yes, but still you can use String#[] to gsub the string

Comment: Which will raise an exception if the String or Regexp within [] is not matched, and parsing a file will throw a lot of them. You can catch the Exception, but then the code will be a little longer, so I guess its better to use the method gsub and forget about those exceptions